# D3.js Heatmap Issue on Mobile Browser and Desktop Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I'm getting an error on a d3.js heatmap app that I worked on in here:

```
https://codepen.io/qwirkyrabbit/pen/XqmPgo
```

It's working well on google chrome and opera in the desktop device (imac) and I'm seeing the heatmap activity in the way that I expect it to be but when I check on any other browser like Firefox and in a web browser in mobile devices (Safari, Chrome), I'm getting unexpected results.

The x-axis was not showing the ticks or tick labels and the datapoints for the heatmap is limited to the leftmost part of the y-axis (not showing anything over the other year spans). Also, it’s not showing for previews on the codepen profile page in mobile as well.

A friend helped me troubleshoot it and he found an issue on firefox where I declared the datapoints mapped to a variable and he got an array full of Invalid Dates: Array [Invalid Date, Invalid Date, ...].

I tested this on Firefox of which I didn't see this particular issue. However, I tried his suggestion of testing to resolve the issue by using a manual implementation of Date.parse(), to no avail.

I also noticed this error on Firefox on the console:

```
[15:09:45.168] Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute. @ https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js:670
```

At this point, I'm not sure if it's coming from my my settings on d3 domain for x-axis, or the datapoints I'm returning for the x-axis for which I'm plotting in the heatmap. Halp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox isn't liking the way you're asking it to parse the date.

Simply change all instances of this:

`new Date(Date.parse(d['month'] + '-01-' + d['year'])));`

To this:

`new Date(Date.parse(d['month'] + ' 01 ' + d['year'])));`

Removing the `-` should fix it for you.

See the MDN [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Parameters) specification  for acceptable parameter formats.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. That solved it on the desktop Firefox browser and I'm not getting any of that NAN issue anymore. I still am getting that display issue on mobile devices though (on iphone 8 with both chrome and firefox). The funny thing is this only happens on an iOS device. I tried it on a Samsung Galaxy 8 and it displays correctly.

Comment: Glad I could help! I can't debug on iOS for you, but you should consider using `alert(Date.parse(...));`, to quickly see if parsing the dates is what's giving you problems.

Comment: No problem at all! I'm glad that I found a solution to one of the major issues on the app and I understand it might not solve all of them. I'm still doing research and troubleshooting so eventually there'll be a fix to it.

Comment: Going to mark this as the  solution since it solved the first half of my problem. The other part of the solution to my problem is listed below.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution for the issue surrounding mobile devices. After I turned on debugging for the iphone, I found the invalid dates array my friend was mentioning and rectified this situation by adding a conditional if statement when running in a mobile device taken from this link ([What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 return x(Date.UTC(d['year'], d['year'], 1))
}
else {
 return x(new Date(d['month'] + ' 01 ' + d['year']))
}
```

Turns out parsing dates for mobile devices required a little change in setting it as a date object. This currently helped me get the correct behavior on mobile devices - Date.UTC(): http://objjob.phrogz.net/js/method/777

Comment: Why don't you avoid using date parsing altogether? You can set a numeric month with [`Date.setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) and the exact year with [`Date.setFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear). That way you don't have to sniff for devices that don't support text parsing.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the pen already just didnt update the link here: https://codepen.io/qwirkyrabbit/pen/JvGawg